# php open listed files/directories on the same page without redirecting

Tags: php, html, apache, listview, ubuntu

I found the php script from this [link](http://www.evoluted.net/thinktank/web-development/php-directory-listing-script) to list a directory contents along with subdirectories on the browser with some style and color. I downloaded from the link and extracted the zip file under apache root directory and I placed all the necessary files and directories under the extracted directory and it's listing on the browser.

I have no much knowledge of scripting. Whenever I click files/directories which are listed on browser it takes to new page and opens them. I'm aiming it to open the files/directories on the same page at the right side dividing with some `frame` or `div`(I don't know exactly) so that one won't need to click back on the browser to go to main page.

I'm pasting the `index.php` from the extracted directory which needs to be changed to achieve what I wanted. Thank you very much:

```
<?php
/*
Directory Listing Script - Version 3
====================================
Script Author: Ash Young <ash@evoluted.net> / www.evoluted.net

REQUIREMENTS
============
This script requires PHP and GD2 if you wish to use the 
thumbnail functionality.

INSTRUCTIONS
============
1) Unzip all files 
2) Edit this file, making sure everything is setup as required.
3) Upload to server

CONFIGURATION
=============
Edit the variables in this section to make the script work as
you require.

Include URL - If you are including this script in another file, 
please define the URL to the Directory Listing script (relative
from the host)
*/
$includeurl = false;

/*
Start Directory - To list the files contained within the current 
directory enter '.', otherwise enter the path to the directory 
you wish to list. The path must be relative to the current 
directory and cannot be above the location of index.php within the 
directory structure.
*/
$startdir = '.';

/*
Show Thumbnails? - Set to true if you wish to use the 
scripts auto-thumbnail generation capabilities.
This requires that GD2 is installed.
*/
$showthumbnails = true; 

/*
Memory Limit - The image processor that creates the thumbnails
may require more memory than defined in your PHP.INI file for 
larger images. If a file is too large, the image processor will
fail and not generate thumbs. If you require more memory, 
define the amount (in megabytes) below
*/
$memorylimit = false; // Integer

/*
Show Directories - Do you want to make subdirectories available?
If not set this to false
*/
$showdirs = true;

/* 
Force downloads - Do you want to force people to download the files
rather than viewing them in their browser?
*/
$forcedownloads = false;

/*
Hide Files - If you wish to hide certain files or directories 
then enter their details here. The values entered are matched
against the file/directory names. If any part of the name 
matches what is entered below then it is not shown.
*/
$hide = array(
                'dlf',
                'index.php',
                'Thumbs',
                '.htaccess',
                '.htpasswd'
            );

/* Only Display Files With Extension... - if you only wish the user
to be able to view files with certain extensions, add those extensions
to the following array. If the array is commented out, all file
types will be displayed.
*/
/*$showtypes = array(
                    'jpg',
                    'png',
                    'gif',
                    'zip',
                    'txt'
                );*/

/* 
Show index files - if an index file is found in a directory
to you want to display that rather than the listing output 
from this script?
*/          
$displayindex = false;

/*
Allow uploads? - If enabled users will be able to upload 
files to any viewable directory. You should really only enable
this if the area this script is in is already password protected.
*/
$allowuploads = false;

/* Upload Types - If you are allowing uploads but only want
users to be able to upload file with specific extensions,
you can specify these extensions below. All other file
types will be rejected. Comment out this array to allow
all file types to be uploaded.
*/
/*$uploadtypes = array(
                        'zip',
                        'gif',
                        'doc',
                        'png'
                    );*/

/*
Overwrite files - If a user uploads a file with the same
name as an existing file do you want the existing file
to be overwritten?
*/
$overwrite = false;

/*
Index files - The follow array contains all the index files
that will be used if $displayindex (above) is set to true.
Feel free to add, delete or alter these
*/

$indexfiles = array (
                'index.html',
                'index.htm',
                'default.htm',
                'default.html'
            );

/*
File Icons - If you want to add your own special file icons use 
this section below. Each entry relates to the extension of the 
given file, in the form <extension> => <filename>. 
These files must be located within the dlf directory.
*/
$filetypes = array (
                'png' => 'jpg.gif',
                'jpeg' => 'jpg.gif',
                'bmp' => 'jpg.gif',
                'jpg' => 'jpg.gif', 
                'gif' => 'gif.gif',
                'zip' => 'archive.png',
                'rar' => 'archive.png',
                'exe' => 'exe.gif',
                'setup' => 'setup.gif',
                'txt' => 'text.png',
                'htm' => 'html.gif',
                'html' => 'html.gif',
                'fla' => 'fla.gif',
                'swf' => 'swf.gif',
                'xls' => 'xls.gif',
                'doc' => 'doc.gif',
                'sig' => 'sig.gif',
                'fh10' => 'fh10.gif',
                'pdf' => 'pdf.gif',
                'psd' => 'psd.gif',
                'rm' => 'real.gif',
                'mpg' => 'video.gif',
                'mpeg' => 'video.gif',
                'mov' => 'video2.gif',
                'avi' => 'video.gif',
                'eps' => 'eps.gif',
                'gz' => 'archive.png',
                'asc' => 'sig.gif',
                'mp3' => 'bg.gif',
            );

/*
That's it! You are now ready to upload this script to the server.

Only edit what is below this line if you are sure that you know what you
are doing!
*/

if($includeurl)
{
    $includeurl = preg_replace("/^\//", "${1}", $includeurl);
    if(substr($includeurl, strrpos($includeurl, '/')) != '/') $includeurl.='/';
}

error_reporting(0);
if(!function_exists('imagecreatetruecolor')) $showthumbnails = false;
if($startdir) $startdir = preg_replace("/^\//", "${1}", $startdir);
$leadon = $startdir;
if($leadon=='.') $leadon = '';
if((substr($leadon, -1, 1)!='/') && $leadon!='') $leadon = $leadon . '/';
$startdir = $leadon;

if($_GET['dir']) {
    //check this is okay.

    if(substr($_GET['dir'], -1, 1)!='/') {
        $_GET['dir'] = strip_tags($_GET['dir']) . '/';
    }

    $dirok = true;
    $dirnames = split('/', strip_tags($_GET['dir']));
    for($di=0; $di<sizeof($dirnames); $di++) {

        if($di<(sizeof($dirnames)-2)) {
            $dotdotdir = $dotdotdir . $dirnames[$di] . '/';
        }

        if($dirnames[$di] == '..') {
            $dirok = false;
        }
    }

    if(substr($_GET['dir'], 0, 1)=='/') {
        $dirok = false;
    }

    if($dirok) {
         $leadon = $leadon . strip_tags($_GET['dir']);
    }
}

if($_GET['download'] && $forcedownloads) {
    $file = str_replace('/', '', $_GET['download']);
    $file = str_replace('..', '', $file);

    if(file_exists($includeurl . $leadon . $file)) {
        header("Content-type: application/x-download");
        header("Content-Length: ".filesize($includeurl . $leadon . $file)); 
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$file.'"');
        readfile($includeurl . $leadon . $file);
        die();
    }
    die();
}

if($allowuploads && $_FILES['file']) {
    $upload = true;
    if(!$overwrite) {
        if(file_exists($leadon.$_FILES['file']['name'])) {
            $upload = false;
        }
    }

    if($uploadtypes)
    {
        if(!in_array(substr($_FILES['file']['name'], strpos($_FILES['file']['name'], '.')+1, strlen($_FILES['file']['name'])), $uploadtypes))
        {
            $upload = false;
            $uploaderror = "<strong>ERROR: </strong> You may only upload files of type ";
            $i = 1;
            foreach($uploadtypes as $k => $v)
            {
                if($i == sizeof($uploadtypes) && sizeof($uploadtypes) != 1) $uploaderror.= ' and ';
                else if($i != 1) $uploaderror.= ', ';

                $uploaderror.= '.'.strtoupper($v);

                $i++;
            }
        }
    }

    if($upload) {
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $includeurl.$leadon . $_FILES['file']['name']);
    }
}

$opendir = $includeurl.$leadon;
if(!$leadon) $opendir = '.';
if(!file_exists($opendir)) {
    $opendir = '.';
    $leadon = $startdir;
}

clearstatcache();
if ($handle = opendir($opendir)) {
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) { 
        //first see if this file is required in the listing
        if ($file == "." || $file == "..")  continue;
        $discard = false;
        for($hi=0;$hi<sizeof($hide);$hi++) {
            if(strpos($file, $hide[$hi])!==false) {
                $discard = true;
            }
        }

        if($discard) continue;
        if (@filetype($includeurl.$leadon.$file) == "dir") {
            if(!$showdirs) continue;

            $n++;
            if($_GET['sort']=="date") {
                $key = @filemtime($includeurl.$leadon.$file) . ".$n";
            }
            else {
                $key = $n;
            }
            $dirs[$key] = $file . "/";
        }
        else {
            $n++;
            if($_GET['sort']=="date") {
                $key = @filemtime($includeurl.$leadon.$file) . ".$n";
            }
            elseif($_GET['sort']=="size") {
                $key = @filesize($includeurl.$leadon.$file) . ".$n";
            }
            else {
                $key = $n;
            }

            if($showtypes && !in_array(substr($file, strpos($file, '.')+1, strlen($file)), $showtypes)) unset($file);
            if($file) $files[$key] = $file;

            if($displayindex) {
                if(in_array(strtolower($file), $indexfiles)) {
                    header("Location: $leadon$file");
                    die();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    closedir($handle); 
}

//sort our files
if($_GET['sort']=="date") {
    @ksort($dirs, SORT_NUMERIC);
    @ksort($files, SORT_NUMERIC);
}
elseif($_GET['sort']=="size") {
    @natcasesort($dirs); 
    @ksort($files, SORT_NUMERIC);
}
else {
    @natcasesort($dirs); 
    @natcasesort($files);
}

//order correctly
if($_GET['order']=="desc" && $_GET['sort']!="size") {$dirs = @array_reverse($dirs);}
if($_GET['order']=="desc") {$files = @array_reverse($files);}
$dirs = @array_values($dirs); $files = @array_values($files);


?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Directory Listing of <?php echo str_replace('\\', '', dirname(strip_tags($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']))).'/'.$leadon;?></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $includeurl; ?>dlf/styles.css" />
<?php
if($showthumbnails) {
?>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
function o(n, i) {
    document.images['thumb'+n].src = '<?php echo $includeurl; ?>dlf/i.php?f='+i<?php if($memorylimit!==false) echo "+'&ml=".$memorylimit."'"; ?>;

}

function f(n) {
    document.images['thumb'+n].src = 'dlf/trans.gif';
}
//-->
</script>
<?php
}
?>
</head>
<body bgcolor="blue">
   <div id="container">
  <!-- <h1>Directory Listing of <?php echo str_replace('\\', '', dirname(strip_tags($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']))).'/'.$leadon;?></h1> -->
  <h1>Music World</h1>
  <div id="breadcrumbs"> <a href="<?php echo strip_tags($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>">home</a> 
  <?php
     $breadcrumbs = split('/', str_replace($startdir, '', $leadon));
    if(($bsize = sizeof($breadcrumbs))>0) {
        $sofar = '';
        for($bi=0;$bi<($bsize-1);$bi++) {
            $sofar = $sofar . $breadcrumbs[$bi] . '/';
            echo ' &gt; <a href="'.strip_tags($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']).'?dir='.urlencode($sofar).'">'.$breadcrumbs[$bi].'</a>';
        }
    }

    $baseurl = strip_tags($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) . '?dir='.strip_tags($_GET['dir']) . '&amp;';
    $fileurl = 'sort=name&amp;order=asc';
    $sizeurl = 'sort=size&amp;order=asc';
    $dateurl = 'sort=date&amp;order=asc';

    switch ($_GET['sort']) {
        case 'name':
            if($_GET['order']=='asc') $fileurl = 'sort=name&amp;order=desc';
            break;
        case 'size':
            if($_GET['order']=='asc') $sizeurl = 'sort=size&amp;order=desc';
            break;

        case 'date':
            if($_GET['order']=='asc') $dateurl = 'sort=date&amp;order=desc';
            break;  
        default:
            $fileurl = 'sort=name&amp;order=desc';
            break;
    }
  ?>
  </div>
  <div id="listingcontainer">
    <div id="listingheader"> 
    <div id="headerfile"><a href="<?php echo $baseurl . $fileurl;?>">File</a></div>
    <div id="headersize"><a href="<?php echo $baseurl . $sizeurl;?>">Size</a></div>
    <div id="headermodified"><a href="<?php echo $baseurl . $dateurl;?>">Last Modified</a></div>
    </div>
    <div id="listing">
    <?php
    $class = 'b';
    if($dirok) {
    ?>
    <div><a href="<?php echo strip_tags($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']).'?dir='.urlencode($dotdotdir);?>" class="<?php echo $class;?>"><img src="<?php echo $includeurl; ?>dlf/dirup.png" alt="Folder" /><strong>..</strong> <em>&nbsp;</em>&nbsp;</a></div>
    <?php
        if($class=='b') $class='w';
        else $class = 'b';
    }
    $arsize = sizeof($dirs);
    for($i=0;$i<$arsize;$i++) {
    ?>
    <div><a href="<?php echo strip_tags($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']).'?dir='.urlencode(str_replace($startdir,'',$leadon).$dirs[$i]);?>" class="<?php echo $class;?>"><img src="<?php echo $includeurl; ?>dlf/folder.png" alt="<?php echo $dirs[$i];?>" /><strong><?php echo $dirs[$i];?></strong> <em>-</em> <?php echo date ("M d Y h:i:s A", filemtime($includeurl.$leadon.$dirs[$i]));?></a></div>
    <?php
        if($class=='b') $class='w';
        else $class = 'b';  
    }

    $arsize = sizeof($files);
    for($i=0;$i<$arsize;$i++) {
        $icon = 'unknown.png';
        $ext = strtolower(substr($files[$i], strrpos($files[$i], '.')+1));
        $supportedimages = array('gif', 'png', 'jpeg', 'jpg');
        $thumb = '';

        if($showthumbnails && in_array($ext, $supportedimages)) {
            $thumb = '<span><img src="dlf/trans.gif" alt="'.$files[$i].'" name="thumb'.$i.'" /></span>';
            $thumb2 = ' onmouseover="o('.$i.', \''.urlencode($leadon . $files[$i]).'\');" onmouseout="f('.$i.');"';

        }

        if($filetypes[$ext]) {
            $icon = $filetypes[$ext];
        }

        $filename = $files[$i];
        if(strlen($filename)>43) {
            $filename = substr($files[$i], 0, 40) . '...';
        }

        $fileurl = $includeurl . $leadon . $files[$i];
        if($forcedownloads) {
            $fileurl = $_SESSION['PHP_SELF'] . '?dir=' . urlencode(str_replace($startdir,'',$leadon)) . '&download=' . urlencode($files[$i]);
        }

    ?>
    <div><a href="<?php echo $fileurl;?>" class="<?php echo $class;?>"<?php echo $thumb2;?>><img src="<?php echo $includeurl; ?>dlf/<?php echo $icon;?>" alt="<?php echo $files[$i];?>" /><strong><?php echo $filename;?></strong> <em><?php echo round(filesize($includeurl.$leadon.$files[$i])/1024);?>KB</em> <?php echo date ("M d Y h:i:s A", filemtime($includeurl.$leadon.$files[$i]));?><?php echo $thumb;?></a></div>
    <?php
        if($class=='b') $class='w';
        else $class = 'b';  
    }   
    ?></div>
    <?php
    if($allowuploads) {
        $phpallowuploads = (bool) ini_get('file_uploads');      
        $phpmaxsize = ini_get('upload_max_filesize');
        $phpmaxsize = trim($phpmaxsize);
        $last = strtolower($phpmaxsize{strlen($phpmaxsize)-1});
        switch($last) {
            case 'g':
                $phpmaxsize *= 1024;
            case 'm':
                $phpmaxsize *= 1024;
        }

    ?>
    <div id="upload">
        <div id="uploadtitle">
            <strong>File Upload</strong> (Max Filesize: <?php echo $phpmaxsize;?>KB)

            <?php if($uploaderror) echo '<div class="upload-error">'.$uploaderror.'</div>'; ?>
        </div>
        <div id="uploadcontent">
            <?php
            if($phpallowuploads) {
            ?>
            <form method="post" action="<?php echo strip_tags($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>?dir=<?php echo urlencode(str_replace($startdir,'',$leadon));?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="file" /> <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
            </form>
            <?php
            }
            else {
            ?>
            File uploads are disabled in your php.ini file. Please enable them.
            <?php
            }
            ?>
        </div>

    </div>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- <div id="copy">Directory Listing Script &copy;2008 Evoluted, <a href="http://www.evoluted.net/">Web Design Sheffield</a>.</div> -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is this a "please operate my webshop for me" question? Could you please ask something specific?

Comment: did you get what I'm aiming?. It's very clear and it's a small work as per programmers but it's difficult for me.

Comment: The script which I pasted lists files/directories and subdirectories on the browser if it's placed in a directory and I just wanted to open them on the same page when they are clicked.

Answer (score 2):

Well what you can do is make use of some JS onclick events, so when each file is clicked you stop the default click action from happening i.e. going to a different page. Instead you'll make use of an iframe to show the URL that was clicked. Here is some JQuery to demonstrate.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('a').click(function(event){

        event.preventDefault();

        $('#myiframe').attr('src', "http://localhost/" + $(this).attr('href'));    

    });

});
</script>
```

You need to create an iframe with an id of `myframe` for this to work. As you can see, all that is being is done replacing the src of the iframe everytime a user clicks one of the files.

Comment: wow you replied!. I just have the idea of frames but don't know about iframe and js. I'll try to read about iframe and try to do it. Thanks!